# How to clean up document without messing up code and place image in the header

Tags: graphics

I am trying some new things and decided to learn latex. I am trying to place my logo in the top left corner but it seems to be too low and I want to place it in the header area so its not where the normal text is supposed to be. If anyone could help with that it would be great!

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{80.0pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-80.0pt}

\chead{\raggedleft \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{example-image.png}}
\title{Newsletter Questions}
\author{Jaireet Chahal}
\date{September 2022}

\begin{document}


\maketitle

\pagebreak

\begin{center}
\maketitle{\Huge\textbf{Jaireet's Math Newsletter}}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\maketitle{\large \textbf{Problem \text{\#}1}}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\maketitle{\normalsize\textbf{23 September 2022}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `maketitle{\large \textbf{Problem \text{\#}1}}` ???? `\maketitle` does not take an argument, and is usually just used once.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle , what can be done about the logo in the header issue?

Comment: Your question is not clear we can not run your example as `logo1124124` is not avalable, and `\text` is not defined. Please edit to use `example-image.png` which is generally available, and remove or define `\text`, and make it clearer what change you want

Comment: the page head is "low" as you have allocated a lot of space to it: `\setlength\headheight{80.0pt}` but that is not wrong, simply your design choice, we can not tell you what value you prefer

Comment: the image is in the head area.

Comment: you example still makes `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> Problem \text`

Comment: How would I make it move to the left more? Is there a way to specify in numbers?

Comment: you have used `\raggedleft` which pushes it to the margin, delete that and it will be centred

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "specify in numbers", but if you want it in the left corner it would make more sense to use `\lhead` instead of `\chead` (and still remove `\raggedright`); you can manually shift it with, e.g., `\hspace*{2cm}` before `\includegraphics` to move 2cm right from there (or use a negative number for moving it further left).